# Creating a user account in Terminal OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mavericks, account

I am trying to create a user account in Terminal and I am running into an issue. I am using the following code:

```
dscl . create /Users/administrator
dscl . create /Users/administrator RealName "Administrator Account"
dscl . passwd /Users/administrator thisistheaccountpassword
dscl . create /Users/administrator UniqueID 501
dscl . create /Users/administrator PrimaryGroupID 1000
dscl . create /Users/administrator NFSHomeDirectory /Local/Users/administrator
dscl . create /Users/administrator UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . append /Groups/admin GroupMembership administrator
```

After running all of those commands I check in the Users & Groups preference pane however nothing shows up. Also, if I go to /Library/users no directory for the account is found either like it wasnt created. The weird thing is, if I attempt to login to the new created account it will login fine but like I stated it does not appear anywhere in the directory or in system preferences. What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix it so it will be listed in Users & Groups and in the library directory?

Answer (score 1):

Try making 2 changes

- Change the UniqueID to something other than 501. Give a higher number 510 or so. The whole idea is to ensure that the ID is not already in use.
- Change the home directory to /Users/administrator.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree with the UniqueID, but the home directory should be able to be in a different location.

Comment: Can be I guess.. I haven't tried. Just thought that this 2 minimal changes, it should work.